# merging css class definitions

Tags: css

I define fonts on their own like this:

```
.smallboldblue{font-family:Trebuchet MS;font-weight:bold;font-size:11px;color:#3A63A5;}
.medregblue{font-family:Trebuchet MS;font-size:13px;color:#3A63A5;}
.medboldblue{font-family:Trebuchet MS;font-weight:bold;font-size:13px;color:#3A63A5;}
```

I also define elemets that are recurrent such menu options or section titles like this:

```
.MenuOptions{float:right;margin-right:0px;}
.SectionOption{float:left;margin:10px 0px 0px 50px;}
```

So when I create divs, I often find myself writing this:

```
<div class="MenuOptions medboldblue">
```

I know I could merge the two classes but I like to have my fonts in one class and another class to handle positioning and such.

Is there a way in CSS to have all MenuOptions be of font medboldblue so that if I want to change the font from a medboldblue to a largeboldblue I do can that change without going through every MenuOptions div? I know I can easily do this with jquery and addClass but I was wondering if there a way to do this with pure CSS.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't do that with pure CSS.

You could use [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/) or [LESS CSS](http://lesscss.org/).

Or you can add the styles from `medboldblue` to `MenuOptions`.

But really I would recommend reading about [OOCSS](http://oocss.org/) if you want to learn about the best way to organize CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Unless I misunderstand your question, you can very easily do that with css.

All the properties that you define in the first section are inherited (`font`, `color`), so you only need to apply your style to the parent / menu element and the styles will be inherited by all menu options.

When you decide to change the font class, you just have to change it for the menu.